# Jhipster .yo-resolve file not working in version 8.0.0

Tags: build, jhipster

Hey been using jhipster for about 4 months. With version 8.0.0 the .yo-resolve file seems to of stopped working for me. It will work for 8.0.0-rc1 but no matter what i try it does not skip over the files I specify.

Here is what I have in the .yo-resolve file which has worked for me in the past. Is there anything I am missing on how it should work?
`src/main/resources/config/application.yml skip src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml skip src/main/resources/config/application-prod.yml skip`

This file works fine in version 8.0.0-rc1 but upgrading to 8.0.0 the file no longer works and all of those files will be overridden

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround for anyone who runs into this issue. Just add the `--skip-yo-resolve` command at the end of generating the jdl syntax and it will force jhipster to call the `.yo-resolve` file. Not sure if this is by design. I'll leave syntax below if anyone needs it as a reference

```bash
jhipster jdl myAmazingJdlFile.jdl --workspaces --skip-yo-resolve
```